# Rendering HTML using Embedded Code Blocks

Tags: html, asp.net, web, webforms

I am looking at some older HTML in an .ascx file which has an embedded code block "<% Some Server Logic %>".  I get that best practice is to control server logic on the server, for maintainability and debugging and.... I see that it is bad. Not my code I am just trying to understand why someone would put this in the code.  Is it just old code that at the time was cutting edge and why it's implemented or is it just junk?

The code is testing a user's role and based on the role they then execute/render the HTML within the conditional statement. Does this prevent the HTML from rendering at all, or should it?

Here is a sample:

```
<% if (userRole.IsInRole("someRole") || userRole.IsInRole("AnotherRole")) { %> 
<section id="someId">
   <div>Some Html</div>
</section> 
<% } %>
```

Comment: The only way this logic would prevent that specific HTML block from rendering is if the user didn't have a role assigned to them. However, without knowing the architecture of the app, I'm unable to determine if it is in fact possible for a user to not have a role. It could be that they are assigned a role as soon as a new user is created.

Comment: Thanks @G.Hunt the question is mostly about the rendering.  I am curious if there is an added benefit of injecting this server side logic in the HTML vs actually keeping it server side.  The rendering of the HTML is very low impact, so I don't know why they'd create the logic or server code on HTML.